# How can I access the value of 'imageCaption' field of a ATNewsItem object?

Tags: python, plone, archetypes

How can I access the value of `imageCaption` field of a ATNewsItem object?

I tried `news_item_obj.getField('imageCaption')` but the result is always `None`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only getting the field itself, not the value. Just use the accessor:

```
news_item_obj.getImageCaption()
```

Comment: But it's really strange that the getField call is returning None... maybe there's some other problem

Comment: Perhaps, but the OP has shared way too little info on their actual code to determine.